# How can I reboot Windows 7 from LAN

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I have Windows 7 installed on one of my PC's. It's up and running. However I don't have physical access to it. I have another PC connected to it through the LAN. I can see shared folders, ping, etc.. Is there any way I can reboot the first Windows 7 remotely from LAN, having administrative credentials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PsShutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541), from Microsoft's Sysinternals group, or you can [remote-desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) in and reboot it in the usual fashion, assuming that you have remote desktop set up.

Comment: No I don't have anything special install on that PC. It is suddenly needed to reboot and I am not prepared...

Comment: PsShutdown worked!

Answer (score 3):

From command prompt on the PC you can access:

```
shutdown /r /m \\yourComputer /t 5
```

(change "yourComputer" to the name of your Windows 7 machine that you're trying to restart)

This will tell it to send a restart to that computer, starting in 5 seconds.

Comment: this didn't work for some reason

Comment: Well that's no good. Was there an error to share?

Comment: no error, just silently completed command but doesn't restart